# SUM above x Cells based on value in Reference Cell

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I am currently using Google Sheets. Suppose:

- Cell C10 is my "Reference Cell".
- Cell C10 has a value of 9.
- Cell A10 is my "Total Cell".

For Cell A10, I want to SUM the above *x* cells, based on the value in my "Reference Cell".

- In this example, Cell A10 would SUM the above 9 cells (since Cell C10 = 9)

How can I do this?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: also... if 9 would be 8 then 8 cells from top or from bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

If from bottom, in A10:

```
=sum(A9:offset(A10,-C10 ,0))
```

if from top, in A10:

```
=sum(A1:offset(A1,C10-1 ,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this if from top:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("C1:C"&C10))
```

[image: 0]

---

if from the bottom do:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("C"&ROW()-1-C10&":C"&ROW()-1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

or from top:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(QUERY(C1:C9, "limit "&C10), "select sum(Col1)"), 2)
```

[image: 0]

and bottom:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(QUERY(C1:C9, "offset "&9-C10), "select sum(Col1)"), 2)
```

[image]

### ___________________________________________________

### also doable as:

from top:

```
=SUM(QUERY(C1:C9, "limit "&C10))
```

from bottom:

```
=SUM(QUERY(C1:C9, "offset "&9-C10))
```